# Pasar un Type como parámetro y recibir una instancia de la clase del Type pasado por parámetro C#

Tags: c#

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un método dinámico al cual yo le pase una clase como parámetro y me devuelva esa clase con datos deserealizados de un api.

La idea es que yo le pase por ejemplo la siguiente clase como parámetro:

```
public class Temperatures
    {

            [JsonProperty("countryId")]
            public object CountryId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("website")]
            public object Website { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Y que yo pueda pasarle esa clase a un método que deserealize la respuesta de un API con newtonsoft y me deserealize la respuesta en el tipo de clase que se le pasa y me devuelva una lista de Temperatures. La idea es que le pueda pasar cualquier clase como parámetro para que sea dinámico.

```
  public static Type convertir(Type t,string payload)
        {
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<t>(payload);

            return obj;
        }
```

De modo que pueda hacer algo así y reciba de una vez la lista de Temperatures o de cualquier otra clase.

```
List<Temperatures> temps=convertir(typeof(Temperatures),json));
```

El problema es que el Visual Studio no me deja pasarle t en la deserealización `(JsonConvert.DeserealizeObject<t>)`, ni tampoco me deja pasarselo de esta otra forma:
(`JsonConvert.DeserealizeObject<typeof(Temperatures)>`)

Comment: Porque recibis Type.. no deberias recibir solo T? vos queres un metodo Generico que reciba un tipo T cualquiera y devuelva un tipo T.. igual, eso no es exactamente lo que hace la libreria directamente? de que sirve un metodo asi?

Comment: como te dice @gbianchi tenes que pasar T, pero si no te deja es porque seguramente tu clase no esta declarada de forma generica. public class MiClase<T>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que una clase reciba T, la debes declarar como tal, entonces en el ejemplo queda declarada la clase y el objeto que recibe como parametro y el resultado del metodo es T. Solo faltara entre los signos menor y mayor `<T>`, pasarle `T`,

En tu ejemplo veo inutilizado el parametro `t` que recibe lo cual solo deberias recibir el string con el `json` que deseas deserealizar.

```
public class ClaseGenerica<T>
{
    public T convertir(string payload)
    {
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(payload);
    }
}

public class ClasePrincipal
{
    ClaseGenerica<string> conexion = new ClaseGenerica<string>();

    public void MetodoPrincipal()
    {
       var resultado = conexion.convertir("json");
    }
}
```